# High memory usage not showing up in Task Manager

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, memory-leaks

I have recently built a new PC, that has been running great but I have noticed abnormally high memory usage. With a couple of relatively lightweight programs running, it is up to 14 GB when the most I can see in Task Manager is 1,5 GB and the total sum isn't anywhere near those 14 GB.

Screenshot from task manager:

[image: screenshot from task manager]

I have done some research and I think this might be due to a driver leak, but I am not really sure. This is the non-paged pool sorted by bytes:

[image: poolmon non-paged pool].

The memory usage usually goes up right after startup, but I couldn't find any of the programs that start automatically causing the high usage due to a leak.

Any advice would be appreciated as I don't know how to fix this. I have 32 GB RAM in my system so it isn't a big problem, but 14 GB used with just a browser and some lightweight programs open does seem to be a bit much.

It could also potentially be a virus but I doubt it since I am really careful regarding downloads and other programs.

Comment: You should look at resource monitor, not task manager.  Windows will keep almost anything in standby memory just in case it'll be used again. The memory will free up if a program requests it. See here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/mystery-memory-leak-where-did-my-memory-go/ba-p/1675369

Comment: @1NN Thank you for your feedback. I looked at RAMMap and I do still think this is due to a driver leak. There are 4.5 GB used up by Driver Locked: [screenshot from RAMMap](https://imgur.com/a/kXLMyF6) What can I do to solve this?

Comment: you should edit this into your question and maybe change the title of the question accordingly, so it gets easier for orhers to understand the problem. Do you have integrated graphics? It could be reserved for the GPU.

Comment: if it's a driver leak it will slowly fill up your whole memory with time .. this doesn't seem the case

Comment: @1NN how would you describe the problem then? I can certainly edit this into the question but I don't know how I should describe it.

I don't use integrated graphics, I have a dedicated graphics card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay turns out it was just me being stupid. I have a VM running on my PC and apparently it was starting automatically for whatever reason. I have now disabled it and everything works as it should.

Comment: Hello, i think i have a similar issue, in that i had tried to run a VM and ever since, even after i closed it, my ram usage stays high. Can you please share , how you figured out that the VM was starting automatically , and how did you disable it ?